# $_FILES Upload file and submit but nothing happen

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner in PHP coding. I try to create a page using $_FILES under XAMPP localhost environment. PHP is 7.2.7 version. The problem is that, when I click the submit button to upload the file, nothing happens. (I use a "if...else" loop to see if all conditions not happen, and the result is nothing happen.)

HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">File upload:</label> 
    <input type="file" name="User Name">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
    <br><br> 
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"] ["tmp_name"];
  }
}
else {
  echo "nothing";
}
```

Comment: You IF condition is wrong... you did not defind an input name "submit" ...isset($_POST['submit']), I would also set an input name without spaces...

Comment: Also $_FILES["file"] doesn't exist. Your input is with name "User Name", not "file".

Comment: @GuyL Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @D. Dimitrov Thank you. I google for the answer and tried some solution in StackOverflow with the similar questions but didn't realize it is my coding problem. It works after I change input "User Name" to "file" and add name to submit button, tq again.

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your form is wrong. `$_POST['submit']` refers to a form control with the name "submit". This can be easily fixed by changing your form to the following:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">File upload:</label> 
    <input type="file" name="User Name">
    <br><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit">
    <br><br> 
</form>
```

Note that I have changed `<input type="submit">` to `<input name="submit" type="submit">`

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks ;) I have another mistake in input's name. The name is not correct. Anyway, the problem is solved perfectly, thank you for your help ;D

Comment: If this was the solution that fixed your problem, please don't forget to mark as the accepted solution, it's much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

First , you din't define a name for the input type submit

To upload a file into the database or  in the directory 
Try this:

```
if isset($_POST['submit'])

{

$filename=$_FILES['fileupload']['name'];

$filetmp=$_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'];

$filesize=$_FILES['fileupload']['size'];

$file_basename=basename($_FILES['fileupload']['name']).date("dmY")."_".time();

$dir="uploads/";

$final_dir=$dir."$file_basename";

//echo "$final_dir";

move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $final_dir);

}

//Insertion Query Goes here........
```

Comment: I tried this solution just now but 2 errors occurred as below:
Warning: move_uploaded_file(tmp/.my.PNG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\file.php on line 31

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'D:\XAMPP\tmp\phpEC95.tmp' to 'tmp/.my.PNG' in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\file.php on line 31

Comment: It works after I changed   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$final_dir);
to
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dir);
Thanks for help ;D

Comment: if it solved your problem , please mark it as accepted solution :D